# Dynamic Space separated inputs in C++ program

Tags: c++, input, dynamic, arguments

I am trying to solve a problem which has likeness of the coding questions asked in programming-war sites like HackerEarth.

Let me give you a background of problem, though it seems to be unrelevant: I am trying to determine how many of muffins can be created with given units of ingredients. The code I have written so far which works with fixed inputs given, is below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N, RA, RB, RC, TA, TB, TC, TM;
    float Temp1, Temp2, Temp3;

    cout << "\nHow many various ingredients are required for creating 1 Muffin? ";
    cin >> N;

    cout << "\nHow much amount of ingredient A is needed to make 1 Muffin? ";
    cin >> RA;
    cout << "\nHow much amount of ingredient B is needed to make 1 Muffin? ";
    cin >> RB;
    cout << "\nHow much amount of ingredient C is needed to make 1 Muffin? ";
    cin >> RC;

    cout << "\nHow much amount of ingredient A is present in Kitchen? ";
    cin >> TA;
    cout << "\nHow much amount of ingredient B is present in Kitchen? ";
    cin >> TB;
    cout << "\nHow much amount of ingredient C is present in Kitchen? ";
    cin >> TC;

    Temp1 = TA / RA;
    Temp2 = TB / RB;
    Temp3 = TC / RC;

    if (Temp1 == (int) Temp1 && Temp1 > Temp2 && Temp1 > Temp3) {
        TPG = Temp1;
    } else if (Temp2 == (int) Temp2 && Temp2 > Temp1 && Temp2 > Temp3) {
        TPG = Temp2;
    } else {
        TPG = Temp3;
    }
    cout << "\nNo. of Muffins can be created: " << TPG;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I know that `scanf` can accept space-separated arguments as input, but that again would be fixed static inputs, which will fail when tested with **Sample Test** case given like below:

```
5 (Total no. of different ingredients needed to make 1 muffin)
2 4 6 8 10 (Qty. of each ingredient needed to make 1 muffin)
20 40 50 70 90 (Total Qty. of each ingredient present in the kitchen)
```

Now I had stopped coding in CPP, since last few years, so I can't get the idea of how do I make my program accept dynamic number of space-delimited arguments, instead of pre-fixed inputs ?

Comment: when the first input is `5` you want to read 5 more numbers? Do you know about loops?

Comment: Yes, no of arguments that can be used for creating muffins depends on first argument entered and yes I still can recall the loops, but I cannot get my head around, how to use loops to get space-separated arguments based on previous input, please let me know on that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop and a vector. If first number tells you number of input:

```
size_t n;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<int> quantities(n);
for (auto& q : quantities) std::cin >> q;
```

No error checking included! That is: Assuming the user enters `n` valid numbers.